# RailsApps mysql2 gem version error with Rails 5.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railsapps

I am facing a mysql2 gem version error while trying to create a new RailsApps example application using Rails Composer. For example, while creating a rails-devise-roles example with the following command:

```
$ rails new rails-devise-roles -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
```

The error is:

> **Error loading the 'mysql2' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate mysql2 (< 0.6.0, >= 0.4.4), already activated mysql2-0.3.21. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)**

The messages on the console indicate mysql2 version 0.3.21 is pulled in

> run    bundle install --without production from "."
>   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
>   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
>   Resolving dependencies....
>   ...................
>   Using mysql2 0.3.21

The generated Gemfile has

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

I am using `ruby 2.5.3` and `Rails 5.2.1`

Comment: Please show the full error. Which gem says it requires `mysql2 (< 0.6.0, >= 0.4.4)`, in the error message? Please show (a minimal sample from) the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`. Which gems do you have that depend on `mysql2`?

Comment: Actually scratch that, I googled the project and the top issue reported is the same as your error: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/issues/279

Comment: A [quick qorkaround](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/issues/279#issuecomment-422095200) is to run the installer with SQLite, then switch it out for `mysql` after the initial step. Or to fix it properly, someone needs to update that project.

Comment: @TomLord Yes, I went with that work around.